# VB.net: Error with mid function

Tags: vb.net

Im making a program that will only accept a userID which is in a format like Hal456, the first one is in uppercase, next two lowercase and the last three numbers.

I tried going through the program step by step and it fails at the second IF statement.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim userid As String
    Dim flag As Boolean
    flag = False
    Console.WriteLine("Input userID to check format")
    userid = "Hal123"
    Dim a, b, c, d, e, f As Integer
    a = Asc("a")
    b = Asc("z")
    c = Asc("A")
    d = Asc("Z")
    e = Asc("0")
    f = Asc("9")


    If Len(userid) = 6 Then
        If Asc(Left(userid, 1)) > c And Asc(Left(userid, 1)) < d Then
            If Asc(Mid(userid, 2, 1)) > a And Asc(Mid(userid, 2, 1)) < b Then
                If Asc(Mid(userid, 3, 1)) > a And Asc(Mid(userid, 3, 1)) < b Then
                    If Asc(Mid(userid, 4, 1)) > e And Asc(Mid(userid, 4, 1)) < f Then
                        If Asc(Mid(userid, 5, 1)) > e And Asc(Mid(userid, 5, 1)) < f Then
                            If Asc(Mid(userid, 6, 1)) > e And Asc(Mid(userid, 6, 1)) < f Then
                                flag = True
                                Console.WriteLine("Format of userID is correct")
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If flag = False Then Console.WriteLine("Format is not correct")

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: It would probably make a lot more sense to use a Regular Expression https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Though that nested If statement is somewhat aesthetically pleasing...

Comment: Yeah, I couldnt think of any other way of making it :/, and im just studying for my exam which is 3 days later... dont want to try anything new..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem with the code. It is a simple fix. Just change all the "<" to "<=" and all the ">" to ">=" without quotes.

Reason:
Your Program will not allow "a" and "z" and "0" and "9" to be part of the userid.
Changing it to greater than or equal to solves this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this using Regular Expressions:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim userid As String
    Dim flag As Boolean

    Console.WriteLine("Input userID to check format")
    userid = "Hal123"

    flag = CheckUserID(userid)

    If flag = False Then Console.WriteLine("Format is not correct")

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Function CheckUserID(userId As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("([A-Z]){1}([a-z]){2}([0-9]){3}")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(userId)
    Return match.Success
End Function
```

Comment: Think you can simplify that to "[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}\d{3}"

Comment: Yes @wizzardmr42 I agree. I tried to keep it easier to read with regards to [0-9] vs \d. but I do have a habit of sticking everything into a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

How about using REGEXP for solving this? I think that should be quite straight Forward.

Something like:

```
        string pattern = @"[A-Z][a-z]{2}\d{3}";
        Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);
        string uid = "";
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please insert userID:");
            uid = Console.ReadLine();
            bool check = rx.IsMatch(uid);
        } while (!rx.IsMatch(uid));
```

Comment: This answer is c# not VB.NET